# CSS rendering in Chrome differs online from offline

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm having the strangest problem with Google Chrome. My html/css layout looks great in all browsers when I preview it locally from a file. But when I upload it, Chrome and only Chrome breaks it. All the other browsers behave nicely, even Safari.

Please have a look at http://www.bakabaka.nl/preview/cefl/

Can anyone help me fix this? And, more important, tell me what I'm doing wrong, so I can avoid it in the future? Many thanks for any ideas!

Comment: I'm using Chrome, and I don't see anything obviously wrong.  What problem are you seeing?

Comment: What is broken in Chrome, looks fine to me?

Comment: *scratches back of head* The error I'm seeing is that float:right and display: inline-block don't seem to be doing their jobs correctly. See http://bakabaka.nl/preview/cefl/images/cefl_chrome.jpg

Comment: It's not looking like that for me at all in Chrome on Windows.  I'd try on Linux if I was at home.  Shift-reload?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess I'll just go with it as-is. I'm using Chrome 14.0.835.202 m om Windows 7, by the way.

Comment: I'm also not seeing anything wrong.

Comment: Same exact version and OS here, @Bakabaka.

Comment: OK. Thanks, and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: These things happen.  Welcome to StackOverflow, BTW.

Comment: url to sample image is broken

Comment: @Sotkra That's because I took it down. It seemed like no one was able to reproduce my bug, so I considererd it solved. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: *checks* Apparently, I can't even reproduce my own bug anymore. I guess Chrome got an update that solved it.

Comment: Alright, well I guess we'll never know then

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's Chrome caching problem, I have been seeing weird behaviors from Chrome several time and I have to clear the caches and history then it works

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, to no avail. It seems to be something that's isolated to me and one of my friends, though -- no one has been alble to reproduce the bug.