# Chrome Renders CSS Differently Online vs Offline?

Tags: css, google-chrome, render, local

I'm having a problem with Chrome rendering my page fine when loaded locally, but something goes wrong once the page is online. The first thing I did was check Safari, because they both share the same rendering engine. Safari renders my page fine.

Clicking on a link on the page and pressing the back button causes the page to load fine as well.

Here is an image showing how the page loads locally on Chrome:
[image]

And here the header is pushed down once the page is online: 
[image]

Here is the relevant html:

```
<!-- header -->
    <div id="header2">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/detailpages/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <li class="blue"><a href="#">Sign Up</a><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
            <li><form><input type="text" name="form" placeholder="type another channel" id="navsearch" /><img src="images/detailpages/search.png" alt="search" /></form></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<!-- end header -->
```

And CSS:

```
#header2 {
position: relative;
z-index: 999;
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
background: #000;
box-shadow: 0em 0em 0.5em #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0em 0em 0.5em #000; /* safari */
/* header nav type */
font-family: "Varela Round", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
}

#header2 ul {
float: right;
list-style-type: none;
}

#header2 li {
display: block;
float: left;
height: 32px;
margin: 10px 16px 0;
}
/* sign up/log in button */
#header2 li.blue {
  background: url('../images/detailpages/login.png');
  width: 170px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}
#header2 li.blue a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 3px 0 24px;
}
#header2 input {
  height: 22px;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  font-family:  "Varela Round", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
}
#header2 form img {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

This guy had the same problem but it doesn't look like there was a solution:
[CSS rendering in Chrome differs online from offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891348/css-rendering-in-chrome-differs-online-from-offline)

Comment: could you put a link to the online version, just to see why?

Comment: @Mark Sorry, I don't have that project available to me anymore. I also removed my hacky answer because that was...not wise.

Comment: I have the same problem. As soon as I load the webpage from the server and not from the disk the navigation is moved down quite a bit. And it looks totally normal in Firefox and Safari when loaded from the server. It isn't a font issue, double checked that.

Answer (score 4):

My bet is you have (maybe accidentally) changed Chrome's Zoom settings for either your online or your offline domain.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> to reset the zoom level to find out.

Comment: omg, thankyou. this was driving me nuts. thought I had lost the plot.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a font issue. Chances are you aren't getting "Varela Round" online and Helvetica will size differently than that font. Offline, you are sizing for Varela, online, you're getting Helvetica.

Comment: Thanks, I checked, but looking at my image it looks like the browser is displaying the correct typeface, Varela Round.